# SQL - When a column has a value from a list and a value not in that same list

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

Not sure the best way to word this but I'm looking for a way to specify a condition when a value in a column has at least one value in a given list AND avalue not in the same list, then that column's value should show up. An example table:

```
email           program
john@john.com   program1
john@john.com   program2
john@john.com   program3
jeff@jeff.com   program3
jeff@jeff.com   program4
steve@steve.com program1
steve@steve.com program2
```

If I have this table and a list of (program1, program2), I would like the corresponding email to show up if the programs associated with a given email match at least one in the given list AND if the given email has a program NOT in the given list

So for the table above and the given list above all we would have show up with the correct query would be:

```
email
john@john.com
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Note: this would be in Redshift/PostgreSQL

Comment: redshift or postgres? please delete the tag that is not relevant?

Answer (score 2):

I like doing this with `group by` and `having`.  Here is a pretty general approach:

```
select email
from t
group by email
having sum( (program = 'program1')::int ) > 0 and
       sum( (program = 'program2')::int ) = 0;
```

In this case, "program1" is required and "program2" is not.  And, you can keep adding conditions -- as many as you like.

I forget if Redshift supports the `::` syntax.  You can always express this using standard SQL:

```
having sum( case when program = 'program1' then 1 else 0 end ) > 0 and
       sum( case when program = 'program2' then 1 else 0 end ) = 0;
```

EDIT:

I think @dnswit is right on the parsing of the OP's question.  The logic would be:

```
having sum( (program in ('program1', 'program2'))::int ) > 0 and
       sum( (program not in ('program1', 'program2'))::int ) > 0;
```

Comment: I reckon the OP wants all emails that have program1 OR program2 as well as another program (e.g. program3). So that having condition should rather be `having sum ((program in ('program1', 'program2'))::int) > 0 and sum((program not in ('program1', 'program2'))::int) > 0` :)

Comment: @dnswlt . . . I think you understood the question a bit better than I did.

Comment: for dynamic list check the technique would be similar, just based on a full join with the items list

Answer (score 0):

if you just want a single list of emails no matter how many times they are on the list by having multiple programs 
it is just `select distinct email from tablename`

Answer (score -1):

First your Data Table is constructed wrong, you should use an unique Identifier so you can retrieve the program version you are specifying.

so your database should look like this:

```
> email           program1      program2       program3 
  john@john.com   ProgVersion1  ProgVersion2   ProgVersion3 
  steve@steve.com ProgVersion1  ProgVersion2   ProgVersion3
```

If you notice of the table above you can now query to get the program value you need for the specified Email. Use SQL Query, your Data Fields for your table are email, Program 1 Program 2 Program 3, when retrieving the value of the fields to be displayed, you are using redundancy you do not need to repeat the email address multiple times for each version of the program.  This would not be expectable methodology.

SQL Query you can use:

instructions: you will create a parameter to use as a variable to query the data table from the list.

```
> CREATE PROCEDURE spLoadMyProgramVersion
> 
> @email nvarchar(50),
> 
> AS 
>
>BEGIN 
>SELECT program1,program2,program3
>FROM  MyTableName 
>WHERE (email LIKE @email) RETURN
```

This will allow you to load all your program version in a list by just specify the email address you want to load, this is a loading stored procedure just use it when you make a SQLCommand Object you can call your stored procedure.

Comment: The answer, is based on the method in which you are asking the question, not the software you are using. Its a simple Query example that can accomplish what needs to be done based on the method in which you are trying to use a table. Also its based on SQL quey

Comment: Ok, if the database is different the SQL method should relatively be the same since, SQL query can be used in a variety of databases the point to my answer was that you apply correct methodology your table should be constructed in format that is easy to query I'm sure that's not limited to any particular database. When programming for database or table and list you should know the methodology is a universal way of applying programming, it should not matter what version or type of database your using methodology is universal understanding how programming is applied

Comment: For instance he gave me an example table so I should him how his table should be constructed, thats one method right there, Secondly I gave him some SQL examples now maybe that example is fitting for another database but the SQL method could be render in like similar way for the database he needs to use his programming for so if you can Read SQL then he should understand how to construct his SQL method the way his program needs. simple it should follow suite and work for what he needs.

Comment: The database this works for is Microsoft Sql Server

Comment: The question the OP posted is about Redshift not Microsoft SQL Server. This answer may be confusing to the OP due to the syntax but there may be some good ideas.